# HAML numbered class of elements

Tags: html, haml

This is what I actually have:

```
  %div.wrap
    -(1..50).each do |i|
      %div.number.num= i
```

I want to generate HTML (from this) like that:

```
  <div class='wrap'>
    <div class='number num1'>1</div>
    <div class='number num2'>2</div>
    <div class='number num3'>3</div>
    ...
  </div>
```

How can I add dynamic classes num1, num2, num3... and also content 1, 2, 3...?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depending on [HAML docs](http://haml.info/docs/yardoc/file.REFERENCE.html#options) you can use this

%div{:class => ['number', "num#{i}"]}